# Почему функция работает только при нажатии меню?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Почему функция работает только при нажатии меню?

Если нажать меню то дерево восстанавливает развёрнутость ветвей.

Но та же самая функция, запускаясь в конце public Window1() ведёт себя странно. При первом проходе ExpandRecursively__Load(tw_tree); получается пустое содержимое tw_tree `{System.Windows.Controls.TreeView Items.Count:0}`. Но почемуто после завершения ExpandRecursively__Load запускается вновь ExpandRecursively__LoadClick. И при этом уже не пустое `{System.Windows.Controls.TreeView Items.Count:**1**}` Но всёравно `if (treeViewItem != null)` равно всегда null.

Меню

Основное

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
             ...
             ExpandRecursively__LoadClick(null, null);
        }
```

Это восстанавливает свёрнуттые ветви из сохранения.

```
 public void ExpandRecursively__LoadClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExpandRecursively__Load(tw_tree);
        }
```

.

```
  private static void ExpandRecursively__Load(ItemsControl itemsControl)
            {
                ItemContainerGenerator itemContainerGenerator = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator;
                for (int i = itemsControl.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                {
                    ItemsControl childControl = itemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ItemsControl;
                    if (childControl != null)
                    {
                        ExpandRecursively__Load(childControl);
                    }
                }
                TreeViewItem treeViewItem = itemsControl as TreeViewItem;
                //при вызове функции через меню, treeViewItem не равно null
                //при вызове функции из кода, treeViewItem всегда равно null

                if (treeViewItem != null)
                {                
                    treeViewItem.IsExpanded = ((Node)treeViewItem.DataContext).expanded;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в конструкторе у вас ещё, судя по всему, не построены те визуальные элементы, к которым ваш код обращается. Попробуйте сделать то же самое, когда окончится загрузка:

```
public Window1()
{
     ...
     Loaded += (o, args) => ExpandRecursively__LoadClick(null, null);
}
```